# Formulario HTML conectado a MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, iis

tengo un problema al momento de insertar datos a una BD, resulta que mi profesor nos pidio crear un formulario en HTML con ciertos datos, conectarlo a mysql y que cada vez que se envien los datos, estos se guarden. El problema que es no se guardan, hemos intentado de todo y no se guardan, usamos php, phpmyadmin, XAMP, WAMP server, MYSQL server, MYSQL full, y hasta el momento nada ha resultado, al momento de dar click en el boton "ENVIAR" solamente muestra en la pantalla el script de php.
¿Alguien tiene idea de como hacer que funcione?
Les agradezco cualquier ayuda.
Estoy usando Windows server 2012 R2 en maquina virtual.
Este es el codigo de mi HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FormularioRegistro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Registro de Usuarios</h1>
        <form action="demo.php" method="POST">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Nombres</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nombreuser" placeholder="Nombres" required/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Num de control</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="id" required/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><input type="submit" placeholder="Num De Control" value="Registrarme"></input></label></td>
                </tr>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el codigo de php:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("<h2>Error en la conexion</h2>");
$db = mysql_select_db("formhtml", $link) or die ("<h2>Error del servidor</h2>");

$nombre = $_POST['$nombreuser'];
$id = $_POST['$id'];

$req = (strlen($nombre)*strlen($id)) or die ("Los campos son obligatorios");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO datos VALUES('$nombre','$id')", $link) or die ("<h2>ERROR no se enviaron los datos</h2>");

echo'
        <script>
        alert("Registro exitoso");
        location.href="demop.html";
        </script>
    '
```

?>

Nota: ya revisamos los nombres de usuario, el puerto, las sesiones, ya tengo conectado mi phpmyadmin con mysql, todo deberia funcionar

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP usas?, por otro lado si te muestra el contenido del archivo PHP es por que no lo estás invocando desde un servidor, en el caso de XAMPP debería estar tu proyecto en: *../htdocs/tuSistema* y luego desde el navegador: *localhost/tuSistema* habilitando tanto el servicio de MySQL como el de Apache

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ya pude hacer el proceso de manera exitosa, usando XAMPP, saludos 

Answer (score 0):

Al hacer submit va a demo.php y si te muestra el codigo php es porque no estas ejecutandolo de la forma correcta. Lo mas seguro es que estas ejecutando el archivo html directo en tu navegador y no es correcto, debes hacer lo siguiente

1. instalas el xampp y prendes apache y mysql, puedes comprobar que funciona colocando esta url en tu explorador  http://127.0.0.1/
2. si estas en windows vas a C:\xampp\htdocs y creas una carpeta para tu proyecto, ejemplo "proyecto" te quedaría así C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto
3. dentro de C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\ colocas el archivo html(index.html) y el .php(demo.php)
4. vas al explorador y ejecutas http://127.0.0.1/proyecto/index.html y veras que te abre tu html y luego al hacer submit ira a demo.php con los datos del $_POST e insertara en la base de datos

Comment: Creo que además es importante mencionarle que si usa una versión mayor o igual a PHP 7 entonces ese código que usa no le va a funcionar pues todas las funciones de mysql_* han sido removidas

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final termine usando XAMPP y actualice mi archivo php con los comando nuevos, saludos. 

Comment: Colócala como solucionada